# How to use gowsdl to connect with soap server?

Tags: go, soap, soapserver

I'm just starting with golang and SOAP service. I want to connect with SOAP server using gowsdl. I've generated with **gowsdl** and got **myservice.go**. What do I need to do next?

Comment: What is your problem? What errors does your code produce? Please ask an actually question instead of asking for general advise.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new client based off of the myservice.go file that was generated:

```
client := NewSoapClient("http://yourEndPoint.svc", false, nil)
```

Use that client to do stuff:

```
resp, err := client.SomeStuffDefinedInSoapService()
if err != nil {
handle error...
}
fmt.Println(resp)
```